# Datetime's NOW() function does not work with PDO-MYSQL prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a database table `timetable` with a `DATETIME` field called `created_on`.

```
created_on DATETIME,
notes VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

I use the `NOW()` function to insert the current time through PDO prepared statements.

```
INSERT INTO timetable(created_on, note)
VALUES(?, ?);
```

So after binding the values and executing the prepared statement...

```
$notes ="This is a note...";
$values =array("NOW()", $notes);
$stm->execute($values);
```

... the `notes` column in the MySQL table writes the expected data but the `created_on` column produces...

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I don't want to use the Unix epoch timestamp. So how do I get `DATETIME` in the  `NOW()` function to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

don't pass `NOW()` as a parameter,

```
INSERT INTO timetable(created_on, note) VALUES(NOW(), ?);
```

so you will only need to bind the notes.

```
$values =array($notes);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `NOW()` as string, not mysql expression.

use as this:

```
INSERT INTO timetable(created_on, note)
VALUES(now(), ?);
```

Comment: But sometimes this can be conditional, so you want a value to be now others different than now..

Answer (score 1):

The keyword NOW() is a MySQL reserved variable and needs to go into the SQL definition, can not be bind. All the SQL keywords (SELECT, FROM, WHERE, Columns names, etc) can not be bind, needs to go into the SQL declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was building the query dynamically. It were trying to add `'current_timestamp()'` as value.

As it's not possible to remove the quote, I change it to don't add this param in the insert method and let mysql handle it.

Now I'm running this SQL query: `INSERT INTO timetable(note) VALUES ('my note');` and the column `created_on` has the default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`;

My full code now:

```php
$tableColumnParams = ...; // this return the composition of the table

$fieldNames = array();
$fieldValues = array();

foreach($tableColumnParams as $param) { // for each column in the table
    if($param["type"] == "datetime" && (!isset($data[$param["Field"]]) || $data[$param["Field"]] == null) && $param["Default"] != null) {
         // ignore
         continue;
    }
    // now we add into list all param that will be in query
    array_push($fieldNames, $param['Field']);
    array_push($fieldValues, $param['Field']);
}
// joining all params
$fieldNames = implode(',', $fieldNames);
$fieldValues = ':'.implode(', :', $fieldValues);
// creating query
$stmt = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$table." ($fieldNames) VALUES ($fieldValues)");
// now I bind value for all others columns
```

If it's a datetime that doesn't have value but mysql has, it will not add it (in insert, in this case) and let mysql handle it.

Comment: Although the idea is viable ("let mysql handle it"), the code suggested is hardly useful. Nobody has an array indexed by the data type(?!) for PDO. Instead, you may suggest to add a default value in the table definition and to omit that column in the $params array

Comment: My own code as this thanks to a `DESCRIBE` call. I know it's a strange things but idk what would be useful for people, so I take part of my code. But I'll edit my answer